# com.samsung.android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STA_STATE_CHANGED does not have support for version higher than 11 (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, wifimanager

Trying to find a new way to keep using com.samsung.android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STA_STATE_CHANGED in Android (Kotlin) but unfortunately after OS 11 (API 30) it does not have support,

does anyone is using this recently with versions (OS 11-14)? or someone else found a different solution to cover this?

this is what I am doing now

```
val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
intentFilter.addAction(com.samsung.android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STA_STATE_CHANGED)
```